# Data WareHouse RedShift versus other RDBMs

Tags: database-design, architecture, rdbms, amazon-redshift

I have a system, where data is loaded at fairly regular intervals, and then later pulled out. Say sales data coming in as sales happen, then later I want to pull in all sales data, row wise, for say a month; max 200K rows in a single pull. Not much OLTP going on; only inserts as new data comes in.

I can use a data warehouse or a RDBMS. IF my data is not running into several TBs, lets say it is 1 TB or so, is there any advantage of using a data warehouse versus a traditional RDBMs without the warehouse tag? What additional thing would a warehouse buy me?

I am asking because I can go with RDBMs, but systems like Redshift talk about MPP processing. Would RedShift be faster because of MPP? Should I stick with plain RDBMs? Notice that I am NOT doing warehouse kind data analytics on the data. Neither is my data going to grow so big that I need slice/multi node capability of products like RedShift. even if I do go with RedShift, I would likely be on a single node.

-Amit

Answer (score 2):

The system you choose (eg RDS vs Redshift) should **depend upon your requirements, traded-off against cost**.

Amazon Redshift is normally a better option for complex queries (eg many rows, many joins) across large volumes of information (eg billions of rows).

Some factors to consider:

- **Volume of data** -- Redshift can store TBs and even PBs of data
- **Query speed and complexity** -- The MPP nature of Redshift can process large volumes of data faster than a traditional SQL database
- **Scalability** -- Traditional SQL databases can only scale vertically (larger servers), whereas Redshift can scale vertically and horizontally. Also, additional Redshift nodes add both storage and processing capacity.

The answer is that you should **try both alternatives and choose what suits you best**. If a traditional SQL database (presumably running under Amazon RDS) suits you well and it is cheaper than a Redshift solution, then that's great!

When performing the comparison, make sure you are including the cost of the database AND the cost of storage (which are both included in the cost of a Redshift node).

Comment: Well the whole point of the question was to try to avoid "try it out". Was hoping to learn from other experience.

I am aware of PB scale of Redshit; that is why in the question itself I mentioned that I am not going PB scale. 

If DB is PB scale, then from my experience I would suggest to go with WareHouse.